# Pagination and content filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

Heres what i am trying to achieve.

1. User clicks a page number based on a number of li elements
2. Max of 10 items per page are displayed
3. The page starts with only 10 items being displayed

I have created the page numbers okay based on the number of  in the html document.

Then a click function has been created that needs to act as the filter. e.g 1 displays 1-10 student divs 2 displays 11 - 21.

Here is a link to my code pen http://codepen.io/fun/pen/pbwvYo?editors=1011

Also here is the JavaScript from the code pen.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
        // Count the number of .student-item
var studentItemCount = document.getElementsByClassName('student-item').length;
// Calc pages needed - number of student divs  / 10 rounded up.
var pageCalc = Math.ceil(studentItemCount / 10);
// Pagination html
var paginationText = "<ul>";
// Loop through page calc + 1
for (var i = 1; i < pageCalc + 1; i++) {
  // Pagination html number
  paginationText += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
}
//Pagination html
paginationText += "</ul>";
// Get padination id
var pagination = document.getElementById('pagination');
// Display pagination html 
pagination.innerHTML = paginationText;
// Hide all but the first 10 students when the page loads.

$('.student-item:gt(9)').hide();

// Hide 11 - 54 student-item divs 
// on Click of 2 toggle class to display 11-20 students
$('#pagination li').on('click', function() {
  // Get page number
  var page = $(this).text();

  if (page == '1') {
    // Hides all others apart from first ten
    $('.student-item:gt(9)').hide();

  } else if (page == '2') {

    $('.student-item:gt(9)').hide();

  }

});
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to display a number of divs based on the the number clicked?

Comment: Which database are you using?...you can us something like http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.V3rKr53D-ig

Comment: Looks useful, will make use of botmonster in the future. However this project has to been custom coded, e.g no use of external resources such as plugins.